# custom fields created but don't show in civicrm_value_constituent_information_1

Tags: custom-fields

I ignored error messages on entering custom fields - Turns out they meant something. Can't import data, as *many* fields listed under wordpress:civicrm:administer:custom data and fields:custom fields do not exist in table civicrm_value_constituent_information_1

Advice sought.

[edit] Aidan, I put all the new fields into the constituent group. I am trying to import through Civicrm's built-in import contact function.

Comment: This is the first data in the database. Starting CiviCRM over from scratch is an option.

Comment: Just checking you are looking in the right place: Did you put all the fields into the 'Constituent Information' custom set?  The set determines which table the fields are in.  How are you doing the import?  You generally don't need to know which table Civi is using.  And yes it's often worth reading the error messages :-)

Comment: Aidan, Error messages led me to this table. They said that a field wasn't found there. After I put the field in, they said the next field wasn't there. Indeed it wasn't.

Comment: Aidan, Then I attempted to delete a partially-installed field, and received an error message that the field wasn't found in the constituent_information_1 table.

Comment: I'd recommend starting over from scratch, because otherwise it's hard to know what those errors were.  If this is your first time installing CiviCRM, you may also want to join https://chat.civicrm.org and mention it - you'll probably get a bunch of help from folks who appreciate the value of welcoming newcomers :)

Comment: As Jon says, best option is to start from scratch if you can.